# How to use do-catch functions in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am a novice with Swift and iOS development and I have come across a weird situation.

I am trying to use a do-catch statement to prevent an error, but it seems like the do-catch is doing nothing at all.

Here's my code:

```
extension String {
    mutating func insert(string: String, ind: Int) {
        do { 
            try self.insert(contentsOf: string, at: self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: ind))
        // This do-catch is to make sure nothing happens if there is no √ in the equation.
        } catch {
          
        }
    }
}
```

The 'try' statement does not seem to be doing anything either! I have searched and searched online forums and have not come up with anything useful.

I know Java well, and you can always catch a specific error like:

```
try {

} catch NameOfException {

}
```

But I have found nothing the like in Swift. The error code that is returned is this:

```
Swift/StringCharacterView.swift:60: Fatal error: String index is out of bounds
2022-03-19 17:37:04.234797-0600 iOS-App[18937:2984774] Swift/StringCharacterView.swift:60: Fatal error: String index is out of bounds
(lldb)
```

I interpret this to mean that the `String` index is clearly out of bounds, but I cannot find a method (like Java) to catch this kind of expression, or if I can even handle errors like Java at all. But I want to catch it so that my app does not crash.

I'm using a function to try and locate all instances of '√' inside of a `String`; `myString.insert()` ind is the `Index` to insert the provided `String` value.

Comment: You've hit the equivalent of a `RuntimeError` in Java, the `do-catch` won't catch those

Comment: Can you tell me how, then, I would catch them?

Comment: To add, what might be surprising is that no *error* is *thrown* by the *throwing* expression denoted by `try`. There is a fatal error (exception) caused by  `self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: ind)`. This will crash anytime you try to offset an index past the end of the string. More generally, it looks like what you’re trying to do is to hack in the abilities to use integer indices with Strings. Don’t try to do that, it’s a very intentionally omitted behaviour, because it’s often incorrect. See https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/UnavailableStringAPIs.swift#L14-57

Comment: You don’t catch them; you just prevent the conditions that lead to them arising. In this case, it’s trying to get an index offset off the end of the string. If you give use more details with what you’re trying to do, perhaps we’d be able to point you in the right way

Comment: or you can use `self.index(offsetBy, limitedBy)` which returns an optional and decide if you want append it at the end of the string or simply cancel the operation. You can also declare your method as throwing function and throw a custom error

Comment: @LeoDabus how do I throw a custom error? I know that this should be very basic stuff... But I am entirely green to Swift and iOS in general after being an Android developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add throws to your method signature and throw a custom error. I would also make the method generic and extend `StringProtocol` instead of `String` to support `Substring` as well. Note that constraining to `RangeReplaceableCollection` is required to be able to use `mutating func insert<S>(contentsOf newElements: S, at i: Index) where S: Collection, Element == S.Element`:

```
extension String {
    enum Error: Swift.Error {
        case invalidIndexDistance
    }
}
```

---

```
extension StringProtocol where Self: RangeReplaceableCollection {
    mutating func insert<S: StringProtocol>(contentsOf string: S, at distance: Int) throws {
        guard let index = self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: distance, limitedBy: endIndex) else {
            throw String.Error.invalidIndexDistance
        }
        insert(contentsOf: string, at: index)
    }
}
```

---

```
var substring = "abcde".dropFirst()
do {
    try substring.insert(contentsOf: "fgh", at: 2)
    substring  // "bcfghde"
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a relatively dirty way to fix the unhandled error, like @Alexander said.

```
extension String {
    mutating func insert(sourceString: String, string: String, ind: Int) {
        do {
            if ind > sourceString.count {
              
            } else {
                try insert(contentsOf: string, at: index(startIndex, offsetBy: ind))
            }
        // This do-catch is to make sure nothing happens if there is no √ in the equation.
        } catch GenericError.StringException {
          
        }
    }
}
```